# checking to see if each index of a range contains the same value

Tags: ruby, arrays

Let's say I have an array

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Now the values of index 1 and 2 are changed like so

```
array[1] = 1
array[2] = 1
```

Now I have

```
[1,1,1,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I would like to check if the first three indexes all contain 1

```
array[0..2] has same value?
```

Maybe true is returned if the first three indexes are all the same. Is there a method for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
array[0..2].uniq.size == 1
```

Comment: August is right on top of me tonight. I was just about to post that as my answer, and s/he beat me to another answer 15 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own method:

```
array[ 0 ] == array[ 1 ] && array[ 1 ] == array[ 2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most readable way I could think of is (if 3 months pass and you come back and wonder what does this code do, this will answer it):

```
same_value = 1
a.first(3).all? { |number| number == same_value }
```

This is, assuming you know what `same_value` will be.

Answer (score 0):

```
array[0..2].uniq.size != array[0..2].size
```

This will check if the number of unique elements in the array is not equal to the total number of elements.

In your case

```
[1,1,1] => # elements = 3
[1,1,1] => # unique elements = 1
```

These two are different.